# Facebook developer Account kit settings not displaying

Tags: facebook, account-kit

Im trying to configure account kit. but the settings are not displayed, why is that ?, I have tried to log from 2 devices but still same screen.

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That was a temporary issue and should be fixed now :)

Answer (score 0):

Same is happening here. I've already tried to access it with different facebook accounts and with different projects, and nothing happened.
I'm also receiving errors in my recent registered apps, when tying to send the SMS. But it still works with the old ones.